# Solve $\sin(5x) + \sin (3x) = \cos (x)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve $$\sin(5x) + \sin (3x) = \cos (x)$$

I'm thinking of using sine addition formulas, but that leaves me with a huge left side of equation. How would you tackle this problem? Am I starting it off right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's decidedly untrue for $x=0$.

Comment: Left side is an odd function, right side is even.

Comment: $\sin 5x + \sin 3x = 2\sin 4x \cos x$. It is possible that you got the identity wrong, or instead, you are actually asked to *solve* an equation, not *prove* an identity.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sin (5x) + \sin (3x) = \cdots = \mbox{Im} \left( 2 e^{i4x} \cos(x)\right) = 2 \sin (4x) \cos(x)$$

Hence,

$$\sin (5x) + \sin (3x) = \cos (x)$$

can be rewritten in the form

$$2 \left(\sin (4x) - \frac12 \right) \cos (x) = 0$$

which can be rewritten as

$$\left(\sin (4x) - \sin \left(\frac \pi 6\right) \right) \cos (x) = 0$$

which is easy to solve.

Answer (score 2):

That is just simply not true. Here's a plot of the left-hand side from Wolfram Alpha:

[image]

Comment: I made a mistake when editing the question. I assumed that the OP wanted to prove a trigonometric identity, rather than solve an equation. My apologies.